# ts-node and svg import gives: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

To run parts of my typescript code I run a script like this from my package.json:

```
 "console": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.console.json -r tsconfig-paths/register console.ts"
```

This are the compile options of the tsconfig.console.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-console",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
```

This worked fine. But now I installed a new npm package that imports a svg file like this:

```
var svg = __importDefault(require("../assets/image.svg"));
```

Now running the npm script fails with the following error:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 9... 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
        at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
```

Is there a way to ignore this error, and be able to start and debug my console.ts file?

Comment: If it's a node application, which seems to be the case from `tsconfig.json`, you shouldn't be importing the svg like this, instead, read the file using `fs` module. Importing it like so, would make node think it's a javascript file, and it'll try to parse it.

Comment: I know, but the svg import comes from a npm package